# How to add external URLs to icCube's application?

Tags: iccube-reporting

The icCube's application structure allows to add several extra items, such as a JS Action. Is it possible to use this JS Action (or another item) to link to an external HTML, to - for example - show a help file/ quick reference card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For opening a new page simply add the following to the body of your JS Action:

```
window.open( 'http://www.google.com', '_blank' );
```

is going to open Google.

Hope that helps.